# Closed form of inverse Ackermann function for $kx$, such as $\alpha(kx) = f(k) \alpha(x)$ or $\alpha(kx) < f(k) \alpha(x)$?

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, inverse-function, ackermann-function

Let Ackermann function $A(m,n)$ be defined as

\begin{align}
&A(0,n) = n+1,\\
&A(m+1,0) = A(m,1),\\
&A(m+1,n+1) = A(m, A(m+1,n)),~n,m\in \mathbb{N},\\
\end{align}

and the inverse Ackermann function $\alpha(n)$ be

$$
\alpha(n) = \min\lbrace m|A(m,m) \geq n\rbrace.
$$

How could I find any closed form (if it exists) or some inequalities for $\alpha(kn)$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, in terms of $\alpha(n)$ and some function $f(k)$ (without $n$ involved)?

---

My problem: I would like to show that in Big O notation for sufficiently large $n$ the following will hold:

$$
\mathcal{O}\left(\alpha(kn\right)) \approx \mathcal{O}\left(\alpha(n\right)),~k\text{ - constant number bigger than 0}
$$

or get some nicer inequalities for $\mathcal{O}\left(\alpha(kn\right))$.

I tried to start with function $d(n) = 2^{2^{\vdots^{2}}}$, where the height of the power tower is $n+2$ from [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482940/ackermann-p%c3%a9ter-function-proof-by-induction-power-tower), with inequality $A(n,n) > d(n),~n\geq 4$, but it was dead end for me.

What is better approach to this problem?

Comment: The fact that $A(n,n)$ is increasing and $A(n,n)\gt n$ already gives you the asymptotic $O(\alpha(kn))\equiv O(\alpha(n))$. $A(n,n)\gt\exp(n)$ is enough to give you that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\alpha(kn)}{\alpha(n)}=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The step from $A(n,n) > \exp(n)$ to the limit with $\alpha(n)$ was too big for me, could you elaborate it? Is there any hope for a closed form of $\alpha(kn)$ in terms of $\alpha(n)$ and other function of $k$? I use it for determining the computational cost of union-find algorithm, based on the work of Tarjan, so not only $\mathcal{O}(.)$ is important for me.

Comment: In brief, That implies that $\alpha(n)\ll\log(n)$, and gives $\alpha(kn)\lt \alpha(k)+\alpha(n)$, so $\frac{\alpha(kn)}{\alpha(n)}\lt1+\frac{\alpha(k)}{\alpha(n)}\to 1$. In fact, I believe you can go even further; the rate of growth of $A(\cdot,\cdot)$ is so high that you get that for all $k$, $\alpha(kn)\lt\alpha(n)+1$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, the $\alpha()$ function is so small that it should be ignored. For every $n$ smaller than the size of the universe, $\alpha(n)\lt 5$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki If you will put these comments together as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $A(n,n)$ is convex and $A(n,n)\gt n$ already gives you the asymptotic $O(\alpha(kn))\equiv O(\alpha(n))$; $A(n,n)\gt \exp(n)$ is enough to give you that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha(kn)}{\alpha(n)}=1$ for all $k$. (To see this, note that we get $\alpha(kn)\lt \alpha(k)+\alpha(n)$, so $\frac{\alpha(kn)}{\alpha(n)}\lt 1+\frac{\alpha(k)}{\alpha(n)}\to 1$.) From a practical standpoint, you should ignore $\alpha()$ entirely; for every $n$ smaller than the size of the universe, $\alpha(n)\lt 5$, so it can be treated as effectively constant.

Answer (score 1):

Stronger even, a constant factor $k$ does not asymptotically give a change by more than one

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\alpha(kn)-\alpha(k)|=1$$

since it is quite clear that

$$A(m+1,m+1)\gg mA(m,m)\gg kA(m,m)$$

as $m\to\infty$ for any constant $k$.